# Hibernate's multi tenancy using separate schema

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

### The problem

I have an application build on Spring 4, Hibernate 5 and Spring Data JPA 1.7. I use PostgresSQL as database. I'd like to use Hibernate's support for multi tenancy, but have problem with correctly implementing `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`. I'd like to use SCHEMA stratagey for separating tenants and I'd prefer to use single `DataSource`.

My current implementation of `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`'s method `getConnection()` looks like this:

```java
@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
    try {
        connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
    }
    return connection;
}
```

I take the `connection` from my `DataSource`, which I inject by implementing interface `ServiceRegistryAwareService`, but I'm not sure that this is a right way.

Method gets called when it should with correct `tenantIdentifier` (comming from my implementation of `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`), statement is executed, but in practise, it is useless. Problem is, that queries generated by Hibernate contain fully qualified names of tables including default schema. Can I tell hibernate to omit default schema from queries? Or should I use completely different approach?

### My configuration

I don't wanna clutter my question with too much configuration, I'll paste here what I believe is relevant. If I missed something important, please let me know.

This is part of my application context xml

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

### Side question

Is there any difference between `hibernate.multiTenancy` values `SCHEMA` and `DATABASE`, from Hibernate's point of view? I understand the conceptual difference between these two, but from looking at the source code, it seems to me like these two are completely interchangeable and all the logic is hidden in the implementation of `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, Have you found a working example for creating a schema during runtime when creating a new tenant ?

Comment: Sadly not, we end up with separate database strategy. I wasn't able to remove default "public" schema from Hibernate's queries. New databases are created manually by administrator. It's not a problem for us, since creating new tenants is extremely rare in our application.

Comment: Well we don't create too many tenants evety day, i can still run a batch at night to create the schema manually. But a question before trying to code it, would I have to restart the application after creating the schema manually? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have not much experience with SQL schemas and Hibernate. I'd guess it would would work, but best way to find out is just trying it :)
BTW you got the working configuration for SCHEMA strategy? I wasn't able to get past that

Comment: Have been awake for 30 hrs now so ill crash now. I'll keep you posted when i implement it ;) a bientôt

Comment: I don't think spring data jpa supports multi-tenancy